# Phone connected via bluetooth to car audio system: media audio works, calls don't

Tags: bluetooth, audio, calls, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g

I have been successfully using my Motorola Moto G3, 2015, with Android Marshmallow 6.0, to connect the phone to the audio car (Toyota) system for months.

A few days ago, I received a whatsapp call (media audio) while the phone was connected via bluetooth to the car, and I successfully used the audio car system for the whatsapp call.

Since then, unfortunately, whenever I connect the phone via Bluetooth to the audio car system, only media audio (e.g. youtube videos, mp3, music, whatsapp calls, etc.) is transmitted, whereas calling another telephone I do not hear anything via car stereo.
The phone works because if I disconnect the Bluetooth, the call is active and I can use the phone to speak/hear.

I tried to remove the Bluetooth phone device and add it again, and to disable transmission of media audio via Bluetooth to the car system, but the problem does not disappear.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help. When a Bluetooth device (in your case the car audio system) is connected to a phone, normally an option is available to select what ways to use the Bluetooth device, namely, receiving audio (playing music) or giving out audio (mic), or both. Are you sure you have both receiving and giving enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the phone/device again from the bluetooth car audio system and linked it again via bluetooth, after changing the phone bluetooth name.
It did not work.

I then turned off and on the phone.

Now it seems to be working, not sure how/why though!

**UPDATE: it happened again, and only a complete power off and then power on of the phone solved the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue , i got a solution for the specific media not working on Bluetooth prob. Rename the device . unpair it . restart the phone . and connect again . hope it works . worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue for a while until I found this:

Go to android settings

Search for "Bluetooth Scanning"

Turn off "Bluetooth Scanning" if enabled

Enable "Phone Call" option for the desired device under bluetooth devices (by tapping setting icon next to device name) i.e. your car, Bluetooth speakers etc.

Restart your phone if needed